# Expose knockout ViewMode from function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have next situation...

For some reasons I need to bind knockout ViewModel inside function and call it on specific terms.

this is my code:

```
if (... some conditions ...) {
        var polugodiste = $("#polugodiste").val();

        ApplyBindingsIzostanak(polugodiste); 

        $('#flip-min').change(function () {
            IzostanakViewModel.selectedPolugodiste(parseInt($(this).val()));
            IzostanakViewModel.GetIzostanci();
        });     
    }
```

and function:

```
function ApplyBindingsIzostanak(polugodiste)
{
    var Izostanak = function (cas, tekst) {
        this.Cas = cas;
        this.Tekst = tekst;
    };

    var IzostanakViewModel = {
        selectedStatus: ko.observable(),
        selectedPolugodiste: ko.observable(polugodiste),
        ucenikIzostanakList: ko.observableArray([]),
        GetIzostanci: function () {
            .. do some code ...
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(IzostanakViewModel);
}
```

Binding is working, but I get error when I try calling `IzostanakViewModel` inside my `if`, it says *IzostanakViewModel is not defined.*

Can I and how expose **IzostanakViewModel** from function and use it inside if statement?

NOTE*

I could try something like this:

add this code to `ApplyBindingsIzostanak()`:

```
window.foo = function() {
 IzostanakViewMode.GetIzostanci();
}
```

and then call it from **if** statement, but maybe there is better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IzostanakViewModel` is a variable within the `ApplyBindingsIzostanak()` function.  Why don't you just return it so you have a reference to it?

```
function ApplyBindingsIzostanak(polugodiste)
    // ...
    return IzostanakViewModel;
}
```

```
var IzostanakViewModel = ApplyBindingsIzostanak(polugodiste); 

$('#flip-min').change(function () {
    IzostanakViewModel.selectedPolugodiste(parseInt($(this).val()));
    IzostanakViewModel.GetIzostanci();
});
```